# how to correctly display "deutsche Schreibschrift" in equations

Tags: fonts, math-mode, equations, fontsize

It's possible to use the so-called "Suetterlin" (or deutsche Schreibschrift?) fonts in latex, see

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.german/15805

I find these fonts correspond more to what (some) people use to denote ideals (especially, the a g p and q). However these font do not come with math mode support, in particular when one use them as indices or exponents they are not automatically resized. Is there any way to make this resize automatic?

EDIT: Combining `\DeclareSymbolFont` with `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet` seems it would be the right way to go, but the font is then about 60% the size it should be. Thus my current (unsatisfactory) solution uses `\mathchoice`, as it allows to scale the font as desired (well more or less).  Here is a copy paste of a file to compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{suetterl}
\newcommand{\ds}[1]{%
  \ifmmode
    \mathchoice{\hbox{\upshape \Large\suetterlin #1}\,}{\hbox{\upshape\Large\suetterlin #1}\,}{\hbox{\upshape\large\suetterlin #1}\,}{\hbox{\upshape \small\suetterlin #1}\,}%
  \else
    {\suetterlin #1}
  \fi
}
\DeclareSymbolFont{deusch}{T1}{suetterl}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathds}{deusch}
\begin{document}
bla bla bla 
$\ds{a}^2 + \ds{b}^2 = \ds{c}^2$ 
bla bla bla 
$\mathds{a}^2 + \mathds{b}^2 = \mathds{c}^2$ 
bla bla bla.

bla bla bla 
$\ds{a}^{\ds{a}^{\ds{a}}} + \ds{b}^{\ds{b}^{\ds{b}}} = \ds{c}^{\ds{c}^{\ds{c}}}$ 
bla bla bla 
$\mathds{a}^{\mathds{a}^{\mathds{a}}} + \mathds{b}^{\mathds{b}^{\mathds{b}}} = \mathds{c}^{\mathds{c}^{\mathds{c}}}$ 
bla bla bla.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The font catalogue: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/sueterlin/

Comment: Could you provide an MWE of what you've done?  For example, `\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{T1}{suetterl}{m}{n}` allows those fonts to be used in math with diminished subscripts.  It would help to get a feel of how you are using it.

Comment: I just edited the main question in order to put a file which compiles, and whose result hopefully explains where I'm trying to go... How does one add an image directly to the post?

Comment: Just above the text field there is a button for uploading images (right next to the code markup button).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `suetterl` package loads the font scaled at 80%; you can, instead, load it scaled at 110%

```
\documentclass{article}

% an edited copy of suetterl.sty
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{suetterl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{suetterl}{m}{n}{<->s*[1.1]suet14}{} % 1.1 instead of 0.8
\DeclareRobustCommand\suetterlin{%
  \renewcommand\s{\symbol{28}}%
  \fontfamily{suetterl}%
  \fontencoding{T1}%
  \selectfont}
\newcommand\s{s}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsuetterlin}{\suetterlin}

\DeclareSymbolFont{deusch}{T1}{suetterl}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathds}{deusch}
\begin{document}
bla bla $\mathds{a}+\mathds{b}=\mathds{c}$ bla bla bla.

bla bla $\mathds{a}^{\mathds{a}^{\mathds{a}}} + \mathds{b}^{\mathds{b}^{\mathds{b}}} =
\mathds{c}^{\mathds{c}^{\mathds{c}}}$
bla bla bla.
\end{document}
```

The result with exponents is far from perfect, so manual `\,` are needed. However, the global appearance of this example should tell you that the experiment failed. `;-)` Please, don't inflict this to your readers.

[image]

Comment: too bad... I'll be back with some other evil contraption and torture my readers someday!